# Fill area between two vectors in matlibplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, rotation, seaborn

The following code calculates the following vectors:
the orientation **Vector **(red)**** and **two vectors (blues)** which result by rotating the red vector 60 degree clock -und counterclockwise.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def Visualize(orienVector,vector1,vector2):
 # Create figure and subplot
 fig = plt.figure()
 ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

 # Plot data points
 #ax.scatter(vector1[0], vector1[1], color='blue')
 #ax.scatter(vector2[0], vector2[1], color='orange')

 # Set limits for x and y axes
 plt.xlim(-1, 1)
 plt.ylim(-1, 1)

 # ===== Important bits start here =====

 # Set properties of spines
 ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
 ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
 ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
 ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')

 # Set axis tick positions
 ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
 ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

 # Set specific tick locations
 ax.set_xticks([-10,-5, 0, 5 , 10])
 ax.set_yticks([-10,-5, 0, 5 , 10])

 # ===== End Of Important Bits =====

 # Draw arrows
 ax.arrow(0, 0 , vector1[0][0], vector1[1][0], 
    head_width=0.03, 
    head_length=0.1, 
    lw=1, 
    fc='blue', 
    ec='blue', 
    length_includes_head=True)
    
 ax.arrow(0, 0 , vector2[0][0], vector2[1][0], 
    head_width=0.03, 
    head_length=0.1, 
    lw=1, 
    fc='blue', 
    ec='blue', 
    length_includes_head=True)

 ax.arrow(0, 0 , orienVector[0][0], orienVector[1][0], 
    head_width=0.03, 
    head_length=0.1, 
    lw=2, 
    fc='red', 
    ec='red', 
    length_includes_head=True)

 plt.show()

# rotation matrix clockwise
def rotMatrixClockWise(angle):
 c, s = np.cos(angle), np.sin(angle)
 R = np.array([[c, -s], [s, c]])
 return R 

# rotation matrix clockwise
def rotMatrixCounterClockWise(angle):
 c, s = np.cos(angle), np.sin(angle)
 R = np.array([[c, s], [-s, c]])
 return R  

# center of the poit of interests POIS
POI_X = [10,12,15,17,20,50]
POI_Y = [20,30,25,22,19,35]

# position of the pedestrian 
pedPostion = np.array([[3],[4]])

# range of the horisontal angel view
spanningAngle = np.radians(60)

# calculate the cone 
for angle in range(0,360,5):
 
    
 # calculating the component of orientation vector V0, where the length |V0| = 1 
 x0 = 5*np.cos(np.radians(angle))
 y0 = 5*np.sin(np.radians(angle)) 
 v0 = np.array([[x0],[y0]])
 
 v1 = rotMatrixCounterClockWise(spanningAngle).dot(v0) 
 v2 = rotMatrixClockWise(spanningAngle).dot(v0) 


 Visualize(v0,v1,v2)
```

The output of this vector looks like

[image: output]

I'm trying to fill the area between the blue vectors to obtain a cone like the following:

[image: concept Output]

The distance between the head of the cone (0,0) and the arc is always 5

However, I can't get it to work. I'm new to Matlibplot

Comment: You might consider editing your question to make a minimum reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not completely what you are looking for, but you could create a wedge between the vectors. It would be more appropriate to fit an ellipse and fill the coordinates in between. Here is an example for the wedge.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np
from matplotlib import patches
v1 = np.array((1, 2))
v2 = np.array((1, -2))
base = np.array((0, 0))
theta1 = np.rad2deg(np.arctan(v1[1] / v1[0]))
theta2 = np.rad2deg(np.arctan(v2[1] / v2[0]))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

a, b = theta1, theta2 
if b > a:
   a, b = b, a
artist = patches.Arc(base, 
            width = 1,
            height = 1, 
            theta1 = a, 
            theta2 = b,
            color = 'green')
ax.arrow(*base,  *v1, color = 'black')
ax.arrow(*base,  *v2, color = 'black')
ax.arrow(*base, *(v2 + v1), color = 'red')
wedge = patches.Wedge(base, 
            r = 1,
            width = 1, 
            theta1 = theta2, 
            theta2 = theta1,
            color = 'green')
ax.add_patch(wedge)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The arc patch unfortunately does not have a fill option in matplotlib.

Comment: Note that `ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='datalim')` would update the plot such that the circular arc isn't stretched.

Comment: @cvanelteren. Thanks for the answer. However, the arc is not drawn correctly as the base vector rotates counterclockWise. How can i adust the arc with the angle update/change

Comment: @cvanelteren. the arc must be drawn between the two black vectors. So when the red vectror rotates, the angle between the black vectors always stays the same. However, the new calculation of theta 1 and theta 2 is then not correct the arc is drawn inversly

Comment: @Zang322 you need to recompute the angle, redraw the patch either by updating its properties or removing it and redrawing the patch.

Comment: @cvanelteren. Yes thats what i'm trying to do, since recomputing/updating the angle should occur automatically. However, can't get it work. i can edit the code in the question integrated with your answer for two iterations, so that you can see what is happening. Are you okay with that ^ ^?

Comment: @cvanelteren. Now it works, the problem was in the arctan() as its between -90 and 90. I used arctan2 and now it works

Answer (score 1):

You could figure out analytically the points in the arc (a portion of a circle, so y = +- (1-x^2)**0.5), add them to the polygon defined by the origin and extremities of red and yellow vectors, then use `https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill.html`.

An example of filling a polygon is here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/fill.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-fill-py

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please express that through an example?

Comment: Link to example posted